# What is the difference between "ade" and "daŭre"?

Tags: adverbs

What is the difference between the adverbs *ade* and *daŭre*?

- Li ade biciklas. / Li daŭre biciklas.
- Mi ade laboras kiel instruisto. / Mi daŭre laboras kiel instruisto.
- Ĉu vi ade verkas? / Ĉu vi daŭre verkas?

Comment: Daŭre looks like plain and good Esperanto to me, ade has the feeling of being slang or a hypermodernism. But for the meaning, I don't see a difference.

Answer (score 5):

Edit (July 15, 2017): Because this old answer has received two downvotes in the last 5 days, I would like to underscore that the bold text in the second line of my answer below is a **first order approximation**. That is, it's not 100% true, but it's true enough - and my answer goes on to explain why. It's essentially the same thing that Airvian and and Lumo5 say in their answers.

Please read the whole answer before voting, and if there is a concern with this answer, please leave a comment. If you have voted this down, please change your vote or leave a comment.

---

To a **first order approximation**, the difference is simple.

- ***Daŭre* is a real word and *ade* is not.**

People who are being taught the word *ade* in the Duolingo course are being done a disservice. The decision to use words like *ade* is the result of a quirk of the Duolingo system which requires the teaching of whole words, thus limiting the options available to the course authors for teaching Esperanto affixes.

A Google search turned up 27 references in Duolingo to *daŭre* and 16 to *ade*. Of these, a higher proportion of the *ade* hits appear to be actual sentences in the course - giving the impression that *ade* is a common word.

Compare this to the Tekstaro where there are close to 400 hits for *daŭre* and only 10 for *ade*.

---

The above was a first order approximation. The details are more nuanced. Clearly *ade* is a real word - but it is not a common one. If you're trying to say something, chances are more likely that you're trying to say *daŭre*.

But yes, *ade* even has its own entry in PIV (although it's difficult to find.)

Summarizing from PIV, ***daŭre*** has to do with staying in the same state and not quitting. It does not mean the same thing as *plu* (further). For example "*daŭre labori*" means to work for a long time, not just to continue in ones work. On the other hand ***ade*** contains the additional nuance of continuing or repeating action.

Comment: I think 'ade' can technically be used as a word but it is meant to be a affix

Comment: I tried to say that in my answer,

Comment: Any specific feedback on why this answer was downvoted would be appreciated.

Comment: It's interesting that this answer continues to get negative votes without explanation as to what's wrong with it. If you disagree, please indicate why. Note that as far as substance goes, this answer is identical to Lumo's answer above.

Answer (score 4):

Ne ekzistas signifa diferenco. Preskaŭ ĉiuj afiksoj povas esti uzataj memstare:

- Ni iris en la mala direkto
- Ŝi estas ino
- Tio estas eta diferenco
- Mi ege sopiras al mia amikino
- La mono kuŝis dise sur la tablo
- Ni eku!

Comment: This is true, but it's not an answer to the question. The question is what is the difference. According to PIV, for example, there is indeed a difference in meaning between *ade* and *daŭre*.

Answer (score 4):

I just finished The Hobbit a few weeks ago and *ade* was actually used a lot but besides in that book I've never really seen it much.

Answer (score 3):

**Daŭre** = Continually

**Ad** is an affix. I have never seen that usage of it before. It should be like the following:

Li bicikl**ad**as.
Mi labor**ad**as...
Ĉu vi verk**ad**as.

Comment: This is incorrect.  "Ade" is frequently used in Esperanto.  All of the affixes can be used in various forms as independent roots.  "Aĉa", "ino", "ege", etc. are in constant use.